# Can't mock OdbcException

Tags: c#, mocking, odbc, moq

I'm trying to write a test for my app for when an OdbcException is thrown in my database call. However, OdbcException does not have a public constructor which means I cannot create a new type of that exception, and I cannot mock it.

Usually using Moq I would mock an exception like this:

```
_dataAccess.Setup(dataAccess => dataAccess.MethodToTest()).Throws<SqlException>();
```

Is there an alternative way of mocking OdbcException so that I can test my functionality? It inherits from DbException which also does not have a public constructor as far as I've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use reflection and/or `Activator.CreateInstance` maybe to create it. Or 2. write some code that throws the exception and use it to generate said exception as a return type from the method. :)

Comment: Activator.CreateInstance won't work but I did try your second suggestion and this seems usable, I can't see a better way of solving this problem

Comment: Can you expand on the second point? I am trying to understand that and use it ! I am facing and issue that might require custom exception too - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38209450/repeating-odbcexception-c-sharp

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a similar issue and solved it by creating my own custom exception that inherits from DbException. This will work for an OdbcException or OleDbException since they are DbExceptions.

My custom DbException class:

```
public class CustomTestDbException : DbException
{   
}
```

My mock code:

```
myMock.Setup(mockObject => mockObject.MyMethod()).Throws(new CustomTestDbException());
```

Comment: Not exactly the same thing, but DbException is probably a better thing to be catching anyway since it is driver independent.