# Repeating OdbcException

Tags: c#, database, exception, odbc

I am using the `OdbcConnection` class to connect to an external database. As a part of this process, I am also trying to handle the various exceptions thrown by this class (`OdbcException`). I find that the `OdbcException` contains a list called `Errors` which has multiple `OdbcError`s.

If I provide incorrect credentials, I am able to get the "access denied" error but they are repeated twice in the errors list. The `Errors` list contains two errors but they are not unique. At the user end I see:

> ERROR [HY000] [MySQL][ODBC 5.3(w) Driver]Access denied for user 'xx'@'xxx.com' (using password: YES)
>   ERROR [HY000] [MySQL][ODBC 5.3(w) Driver]Access denied for user 'xx'@'xxx.com' (using password: YES)

How do I handle this situation and make them unique? I tried doing it manually by creating a new `OdbcException` and removing the repeated error item in the list but I couldn't do that. (I guess `OdbcException` doesn't have a public constructor). Is creating a custom exception that mocks the same ODBC exception the only way? How will I create a custom exception? Should it inherit `OdbcException` or `DbException`?

Comment: Are you sure that these exceptions are not unique?

Comment: It is one single exception but the errors list contains repeating items. Even at the user end, I see the same error repeated twice.

Comment: @Jaroen Ive modified my question to include the user error